# Qt project + MATLAB

Tags: matlab, qt-creator

I have a `MatLab` script the generates some array of values and the values should be used as input in the `Qt` project and the generated output used in the `MatLab` script.

Could some one tell how to do this?

Comment: You need to give more specific information if anyone's going to be able to help you. Are you trying to integrate your C++ code into your matlab code using mex (in which case, add the 'mex' tag to your question), or does your Qt project compile to a standard executable file which you'd like to be able to call...

Answer (score 1):

I think you shall compile your `Qt` project.

Call your first `MatLab` script.

When the script finished it's job try to evaluate the compiled `Qt` code.

```
try
    eval( [ '! applicationFilename' ] ); % Pass input arguments if available.
catch ME
    disp( ME.message );
end
```

When it's done, call your second `MatLab` script.

What you need to decide is how the language shall comminicate ? Will you write array into a file then the `Qt` application reads it and write it's own result into an other file ? Or some other way.